# Trying to get one element from an array using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get randomly one item from an array using mongoose, I use `.aggregate`:

```js
const winner = await gSchema.aggregate(
                        [ 
                            { "$unwind": "$Users" }, 
                            { "$sample": { "size": 1 } } 
                        ]
                    )
```

I `console.log(winner)` I get:

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("62c0943a789817d59c19bfa4"),
    Guild: '1234567889',
    Host: '1234567889',
    Channel: '1234567889',
    MessageID: '1234567889',
    Time: '86400000',
    Date: 2022-07-02T18:53:46.981Z,
    Users: '1234567889',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

Instead, I want to only get the value of `Users` like: `1234567889` in my console, not the whole Schema, any idea how to achieve that?

Also is there a way to use filter when using `aggregate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick update about the issue, using `console.log(winner[0].Users)` solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

In order to get only the `Users` data add a projection step:

```
const winner = await gSchema.aggregate(
                        [ 
                            {$unwind: "$Users"}, 
                            {$sample: {size: 1}},
                            {$project: {Users: 1, _id:0}}
                        ]
                    )
```

In order to filter, add a `$match` step.

Comment: I still get 
`[ { Users: '123456789' } ]` I am trying to only get the value without anything else like this: `123456789`

Comment: I'm not familiar with such an option. The aggregation pipeline returns an array of objects, so this is the minimal option that I'm aware of.